# How do I enumerate open windows in a different session from a service?

Tags: wtsapi32

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308135/how-can-i-enumerate-the-open-windows-enumwindows-of-another-user-session), but I was hoping to avoid using `CreateProcessAsUser`. I can enumerate windows by calling `EnumDesktopWindows`, and I can get the desktops by calling `EnumDesktops`. Unfortunately, `EnumDesktops` requires a window station name, and `WTSQuerySessionInformation` with `WTSWinStationName` [explicitly does not](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383861.aspx) return the window station name.

So, I guess my question is: how do I get hold of the Window Station for a WTS session?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [EnumWindowStations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682644%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).
For more background please see this blog post I wrote on [Sessions, Window Stations, and Desktops](http://www.brianbondy.com/blog/id/100/understanding-windows-at-a-deeper-level-sessions-window-stations-and-desktops).

Comment: It's been a while, but I seem to recall that this always returns "WinSta0". How do I find out the window stations *for a particular session*? Or: how do I pass a *session* to EnumDesktops?

Comment: You can start a process within a particular session and then use that API.

Comment: "...but I was hoping to avoid using CreateProcessAsUser...". Unfortunately, that's what I ended up doing.